# Getting VMWare DataStore inventory data (inventory traversal)

Tags: vmware, datastore, esxi

I'm attempting to get typical properties (capacity, free space, name) from the DataStores in my VMware ESXi server.  I'm having trouble getting the TraversalSpec, ObjectSpec and PropertySpecs.

Can someone please tell me what I'm doing wrong?

```
public void GetDataStoreValues()
{
    PropertyFilterSpec spec = GetDataStoreQuery();

    ObjectContent[] objectContent = _service.RetrieveProperties(_sic.propertyCollector, new[] { spec } );
    foreach (ObjectContent content in objectContent)
    {
        if (content.obj.type == "DataStore")
        {
            //... get values
        }
    }
}

private PropertyFilterSpec GetDataStoreQuery()
{
    try
    {
        // Traversal to get to the host from ComputeResource
        TraversalSpec tSpec = new TraversalSpec
        {
            name = "HStoDS",
            type = "HostSystem",
            path = "dataStore",
            skip = false
        };

        // Now create Object Spec
        var objectSpec = new ObjectSpec
        {
            obj = _sic.rootFolder,
            skip = true,
            selectSet = new SelectionSpec[] { tSpec }
        };
        var objectSpecs = new[] { objectSpec };

        // Create PropertyFilterSpec using the PropertySpec and ObjectPec
        // created above.
        // Create Property Spec
        string[] propertyArray = new[] {
                                        "summary.capacity"
                                        ,"summary.freeSpace"
                                        ,"summary.name"
                                      };
        var propertySpec = new PropertySpec
        {
            all = true,
            pathSet = propertyArray,
            type = "DataStore"
        };
        var propertySpecs = new[] { propertySpec };

        var propertyFilterSpec = new PropertyFilterSpec
        {
            propSet = propertySpecs,
            objectSet = objectSpecs
        };

        return propertyFilterSpec;
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
    }
    return null;
}
```

Also, are object type names case sensitive?  I seem to see all sorts of cases when I look at samples.

Thanks for any suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**First question:** You can use the following code to get properties of DataStore. I tested this code on vCenter 5.1

```
public void Test()
{
    var properties = GetProperties(
        new ManagedObjectReference { type = "Datastore", Value = "<your_datastore_key>" },
        new[] {"summary.capacity", "summary.freeSpace", "summary.name"});
}

private List<DynamicProperty> GetProperties(ManagedObjectReference objectRef, string[] properties)
{
    var typesAndProperties = new Dictionary<string, string[]> { { objectRef.type, properties } };
    var objectContents = RetrieveResults(typesAndProperties, new List<ManagedObjectReference> { objectRef });
    return ExtractDynamicProperties(objectRef, objectContents);
}

private List<ObjectContent> RetrieveResults(Dictionary<string, string[]> typesAndProperties, List<ManagedObjectReference> objectReferences)
{
    var result = new List<ObjectContent>();
    var tSpec = new TraversalSpec { path = "view", skip = false };
    var oSpec = new ObjectSpec { skip = true, selectSet = new SelectionSpec[] { tSpec } };
    oSpec.obj = service.CreateListView(serviceContent.viewManager, objectReferences.ToArray());
    tSpec.type = "ListView";

    var fSpec = new PropertyFilterSpec
    {
        objectSet = new[] { oSpec },
        propSet = typesAndProperties.Keys.Select(typeName => new PropertySpec { type = typeName, pathSet = typesAndProperties[typeName] }).ToArray()
    };

    PropertyFilterSpec[] pfs = { fSpec };
    var retrieveResult = service.RetrievePropertiesEx(serviceContent.propertyCollector, pfs, new RetrieveOptions());
    if (retrieveResult != null)
    {
        result.AddRange(retrieveResult.objects);
        while (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(retrieveResult.token))
        {
            retrieveResult = service.ContinueRetrievePropertiesEx(serviceContent.propertyCollector, retrieveResult.token);
            result.AddRange(retrieveResult.objects);
        }
        service.DestroyView(oSpec.obj);
    }
    return result;
}

private static List<DynamicProperty> ExtractDynamicProperties(ManagedObjectReference objectRef, IEnumerable<ObjectContent> objectContents)
{
    var result = new List<DynamicProperty>();
    foreach (var objectContent in objectContents)
    {
        if (objectContent.propSet == null) continue;
        if (objectContent.obj == null) continue;
        if (objectContent.obj.type != objectRef.type || objectContent.obj.Value != objectRef.Value) continue;
        result.AddRange(objectContent.propSet);
    }
    return result;
}
```

**How to run the sample:**

1. Initialize the `service` by object of `VimService` class and the `serviceContent` by object of `ServiceContent` class.
2. Login to vCenter or ESX using `service`.
3. Replace `<your_datastore_key>` with Key of your datastore. You can use the [Managed Object Browser](http://pubs.vmware.com/vsphere-50/index.jsp?topic=/com.vmware.wssdk.pg.doc_50/PG_ChB_Using_MOB.20.1.html) to find keys of their datastores. To get a description of datastore object, go to following links in MOB: content -> rootFolder -> childEntity -> datastoreFolder -> childEntity. Value of "Managed Object ID" on top of page is correct Key (like `datastore-46`).

**Second question:** Yes, the type of ManagedObjectReference is case sensitive.

Comment: I get null back for retrieveResult :(   I thought maybe it had something to do with datastore-46, but even setting it to my local datastore name didn't help (and I can't hard-code datastore names anyway)

Comment: I updated my answer and described how to get the datastore Key. It's only sample getting properties of datastore. If you need to get list of datastores, you can do it using MOB, SDK Documentation and my implementation of GetProperties() method. It's really not a difficult task.

Comment: I'm sorry I'm such a noob, but what is MOB?  Managed Object?  I keep reading that Datastore isn't a Managed Object.  I think my problem is I'm just not understanding how traversals are done, and the documentation hasn't helped my cob-webbed brain :(

Comment: MOB is Managed Object Browser, see link in my answer. It's a useful web-based utility to explore data objects (like Datastore, Datacenter, VirtualMachine, Permission etc) and to invoke methods these objects from web browser. With this tool you can view all keys and types of managed objects, then use them in your code samples to create ManagedObjectReference. Also you can view property of objects and relationships between objects.

Comment: In the initial stages of nuances of working with TraversalSpec are not important. Using ServiceContent you can get any manager and searchIndex, rootFolder objects (read SDK documentation about these objects!). Then you can using VimService to invoke any method of these objects and using GetProperties() to get any properties. Hope it helps you start using VMware API. If you'll get problems please write about it, I'll try to help.